# If $M_m=0\forall m\in \operatorname{Specm}(A)$ s.t. $m\supset I$, then $M=IM$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

I am dealing with the following question:

> Let $M$ be an $A$-module and $I$ an ideal of $A$. Suppose that $M_m=0\;\forall m\in \operatorname{Specm}(A)$ s.t. $m\supset I$. Then $M=IM$.

(Here, $M_m$ is the localization by the ideal $m$, i.e., $S^{-1}M$, $S^{-1}=A\setminus m.$)

I've found an answer in this post: [$M_m=0$ for every maximal ideal $m$ containing $I$ if and only if $M=IM$, where $M$ is finite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950717/m-m-0-for-every-maximal-ideal-m-containing-i-if-and-only-if-m-im-where)

It's reproduced below:

*Consider the $R$-module $\overline{M}=M/IM$ and let $m\subseteq R$ be a maximal ideal of $R$. If $I\not\subseteq m$, then $I_m=R_m$ and $\overline{M}_m=0$. If $I\subseteq m$ then by assumption $M_m=0$ and $\overline{M}_m=0$. Hence $\overline{M}=0$. i.e. $M=IM$.*

However, I could not understand the most important part to me:

> If $I\not\subseteq m$, then $I_m=R_m$ and $\overline{M}_m=0$.

Please, could someone fill with more details?

Many thanks!

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: I suppose `Specm` denotes the maximal spectrum?

Comment: @anomaly, sorry, First why $I_m=R_m$ (I know that $I_m<R_m$). Thank you.

Comment: @Bernard, yes! Thank you.

Comment: And what is $\overline M$? $M/IM$?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, it's the notation of the link. I reproduced it at post now, please see the edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I\nsubseteq \mathfrak m$, at least one element of $I$ is not in $\mathfrak m$, hence is invertible in $R_{\mathfrak m}$ and thus $I_{\mathfrak m}$ contains the unit element of $R_{\mathfrak m}$.

If $\overline M$ denotes $M/IM$, its localisation at $\mathfrak m$ is
$$(M/IM)_{\mathfrak m}\simeq M_{\mathfrak m}/(IM)_{\mathfrak m}=M_{\mathfrak m}/I_{\mathfrak m}M_{\mathfrak m}=M_{\mathfrak m}/M_{\mathfrak m}=\{0\}.$$

Comment: Understood, thank you for the help with my studies once again, Mr. Bernard.

Comment: You're (again) welcome. 'Tis always a pleasure to help!